# Print those elements from array1 which are not in array2

Tags: perl, difference

I have an assignment that is asking for the difference of two *arrays*. More specifically we are asked "The result is an array that contains elements that exist in the first array but not in the second."

Does this mean that the 3rd array which is my output should have the intersection of values that exist in both arrays? For example I have two arrays:

```
@list1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
@list2 = ( 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15 );
```

Is my output supposed to be `( 3, 5, 7 )`?

Comment: It looks like you should be asking about the meaning of "difference" in your assignment.  This isn't a Perl specific question.

Comment: @NathanFellman: This isn't a difference `A ∆ B` it's a relative complement `A - B`

Comment: Regardless, this is a question of understanding the question. Maybe it's a question of understanding set theory. It's not a question in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

> The result is an array that contains elements that exist in the first
>   array but not in the second.

That means the desired output is `(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9)`.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/glFkAJ):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
my @array1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ) ; 
my @array2 = ( 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15 ) ;
my %tmp ;

# Store all entries of array2 as hashkeys (values are undef) using a hashslice
@tmp{@array1} = undef ; 

# delete all entries of array1 from hash using another hashslice
delete @tmp{@array2} ;
printf "In Array1 but not in Array2 : %s\n" , join( ',' , keys %tmp ) ;
```

Using [**Array::Utils**](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.3/Utils.pm) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);
my @a = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 );
my @b = qw( 3 5 7 11 13 15 );
my @minus = array_minus(@a, @b);
print @minus;
```

Also check perlfaq for: [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?--How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?)?